# Dúvida sobre each() no Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Porque o código abaixo só me retorna o primeiro "104 104" e não "104 106"

```js
$(function(){
  $('#sortable li').each(function(){
    console.log($('#sortable li').attr('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li id="104"></li>
  <li id="106"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Podes juntar o HTML? assim podemos responder mais pedagogicamente. De modo breve estás sempre a usar o mesmo elemento... deves usar `console.log(this.id);`. Mas se juntares o HTML é mais fácil perceber o problema e responder.

Answer (score 4):

Quando usas `$('#sortable li').attr('id')` o jQuery vai retornar somente o `id` do primeiro elemento que esse seletor encontrar.

Quando usas essa linha de código dentro de um `.each()` não estás na verdade a mudar nada, e daí ele dar a mesma resposta nas duas vezes.

Contudo o seletor `$('#sortable li')` retorna todos os elementos que queres e faz sentido usar o `.each()` para os iterar. Sendo que o jQuery atribui o elemento iterado ao `this` dentro dessa função passada ao `.each()` então para saberes o `id` basta usares `this.id`, [como referi no meu comentário antes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/94371/d%C3%BAvida-sobre-each-no-jquery#comment191439_94371).

Assim basta usares:

```
$('#sortable li').each(function(){
    console.log(this.id);
});
```

**NOTA:** repara que te falta `});`  no final do teu código, antes do `</script>`.

Answer (score 2):

Porque a cada giro do loop você está fazendo uma nova consulta ao DOM.
 
A estrutura do $.each(); permite que você acesse o index do elemento e o próprio elemento, sem refazer a consulta ao DOM:

```
$('#sortable li').each(function(i, o){
   console.log(o.id);
});
```

Comment: o `this` retorna o elemento atual do for tb dentro do bloco. Ex: `$(this).attr("id")`

Comment: kkk eu sei Bruno, é pq escrevi rapido aqui e nem reparei. O html ta em cima Sergio. Marcelo, entendi. Mas como faço para obter os ids das duas li. To apanhando aqui, pra essa porcaria. :)

Comment: acumula eles em um array ou em uma string, não sei se entendi ao certo sua duvida... cada volta do loop ele vai te expor o id do atual e então vc vai acumulando em alguma variável que foi declarada fora do loop (each)

Comment: Acabei de descubrir...rss Vlw galera...

Answer (score 0):

é isso?

```
$("#sortable li").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lqmf8g20/

Answer (score -1):

Olá segue um exemplo onde exibirá os atributos "id" em um 'alert' do Javascript:

```
 $("#sortable li").each(function(ui, e){
     alert($(this).attr("id"));
 });
```

Comment: Seria útil se acrescentasse  à sua resposta uma pequena explicação.